# How to Set App-Specific notifications/vibrations?

Tags: notifications

I recently switched from an iPhone to a Galaxy S8, and with the iPhone I was able to set app-specific notification sounds and vibration patterns (1 for texts, another for email, another for group messages, and so on).

Is this possible within the Android OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to *Settings→Notifications→App from List*

Be sure not to press the slide check, otherwise that turns off notifications.

If the notification has a sound, it will say something like "Make sound", then you can change it from the default. If not it will say "No sound".